# PDO update_user function

Tags: php, security, pdo

Is is secure to use the update_user function like this?

```
function update_user($update_data) {
    global $pdo;

    $update = array();

    foreach($update_data as $field=>$data){
    $update[] = '`'. $field.'` = \''. $data.'\''; 
    }
    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET " . implode(', ', $update) ."WHERE user_id = " .$_SESSION['user_id']);
    $query->execute(); 
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you use that function, i.e. what `$update_data` actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not.
You have insufficient formatting for the identifiers and strings.
and you're not using placeholders which distinguish PDO from older extension.

In the [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) you can find an example that uses a helper function for this task.
Using a function from there you can make it this way

This function can be used this way:

```
function update_user($allowed) {
    global $pdo;
    $allowed = array("name","surname","email","password"); // allowed fields
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET ".pdoSet($allowed,$values)." WHERE id = :id";
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $values["id"] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $stm->execute($values);
}
// usage:
update_user();
```

Please note that this function will take values directly from the $_POST array, so 2 important things needs to be mentioned:

- no need to create $input_data manually
- if there are fields that absent in the $_POST array (hashed password for example), they have to be added there manually.

However, if you have your `$input_data` already whitelisted (i.e. created in your script with all field names hardcoded), it's o.k. to use deceze's solution too.
**But if `$input_data` is coming from the client side, his solution is vulnerable to SQL injection**

Answer (score -1):

No. Your use of prepared statements is pointless and the data is not escaped. Use properly prepared statements like this:

```
$fields = array_map(function ($key) { return "`$key` = :$key"; }, array_keys($update_data));
$query  = sprintf('UPDATE users SET %s WHERE user_id = :userId', join(', ', $fields));
$stmt   = $pdo->prepare($query);

forach ($update_data as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value);
}
$stmt->bindParam(':userId', $_SESSION['user_id']);

$stmt->execute();
```

This assumes at least the array keys are whitelisted values which won't cause syntax problems.